# What is the use of plain variable access in Python?

Tags: python

In python this kind of syntax is accepted and runs correctly

```
foo = "test variable"
foo # plain variable access
foo # plain variable access
print(foo)
>>>>test variable
```

**Q:** So my question is, what is the use-case in the context of Python ? Several other languages would highlight that as a syntax error.

---

In order to make sure something was happening, I used the `dis` module and got the following output

```
def test():
    foo = "test variable"
    foo
    return foo

dis.dis(test)
>>>>3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('test variable')
                2 STORE_FAST               0 (foo)

    4           4 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
                6 POP_TOP

    5          12 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              14 RETURN_VALUE

def test():
    foo = "test variable"
    return foo

dis.dis(test)
>>>>9           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('test variable')
                2 STORE_FAST               0 (foo)

   10           4 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
                6 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, there is this extra operation which I can't seems to understand.

```
 4 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
 6 POP_TOP
```

Comment: Note that if I should remove the suggested other question I would understand. Also, if there is a specific name for those type of call in python I will edit.

Comment: Because Python is not C#? Note that I can do the same thing in e.g. C (though the compiler will likely throw a warning).

Comment: I understand that C# is not Python. I'm asking if there is a use case since it is accepted.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "variable call" (too close to "function call"); perhaps "variable access". To avoid confusion.

Comment: Well, you ask why it's accepted in Python; I see no question about  use case. But because the language is defined that way.

Comment: A simple use case is in the interpreter, the Python prompt: `foo` on its own will display its value.

Comment: _because the language is defined that way_ This can be use to answer pretty much any questions. I just like to think there is a reason for it.

Comment: Then I suggest to [edit] your question, and change both the title and main question in the text, to e.g. "What is the use of a plain variable by itself in Python?" That is a slightly different, but hopefully, clearer question than "why".

Comment: @9769953 Thanks for the insights I have to admit the question seems clearer like that.

Comment: That's what the comments are for: to ask for clarification, and hopefully improve the question. Seems that that has worked. I'll shortly be deleting the comments leading up to your edit, since they are not needed anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There are no uses, no, except in the case of a REPL as a shortcut to `print(repr(var) if var is not None else '')`:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> x
3
```

`LOAD_FAST` adds the variable to the stack and then `POP_TOP` removes it. Nothing actually happens.

---

Why is this allowed? Well, because it's simpler than not. I mean we'd have to be careful to allow `func()` but not `func`. It also get's more complicated when we use attributes, for example:

```
class T:
    def __init__(self):
         self.gets = 0
    @property
    def attr(self):
        self.gets += 1

t = T()
print(t.gets)  # 0
t.attr
print(t.gets)  # 1
```

so even the act of referencing a "plain attribute" can have side effects.

Comment: I see, but when running it from a script, nothing will happen at those lines, can this be overridden ?

Comment: What do you mean overridden? As in forcing something to happen? Or forcing a warning (most IDE's will warn for this anyway)?

Comment: I mean if I were to use only `t` on a single line in your above code, nothing will happen. Is there a special method related to that. Can I force something to happen when I only use the name of the variable.

Comment: No, you can't. That would be very confusing.

Comment: Well considering it has a behavior in the intepreter I don't know if it would that confusing in code.

Comment: I mean would it be impossible to have the same behavior when using it the console than in code ? If you just don't I will open a new thread which is more appropriate than this one for what I'm looking for.

Comment: No that's not possible. I don't see what the issue is with creating a new function and just passing that. `def p(x): print(repr(x))` `p(var)` `p(var2)`. Much more clear.

Comment: I'm not saying it is a problem, I'm curious to know if it would be possible. I mean declaring a function would imply the use of the callable version `p()` instead of just changing the behavior of plain access like `var`

Comment: .... yes. But you must see that is much clearer to someone reading your code is. My answer is that it is not possible **and** there is no advantage of it except saving typing 3 characters!

Comment: @scharette I suspect that it would be possible to modify the behaviour of `t` (without making a full on interpreter), after all `t` is still looked-up in the appropriate name-space and if not defined this will throw a `NameError` (no actual good use cases for this though)

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes, as I said, I'm not trying to find a specific use-case for it, I just find it very interesting to know if it would be possible to have the same behavior in-code than in the console for that type of call.

Answer (score 1):

The additional `foo`s have **no observable effect**. The dis output shows that the value is loaded then immediately discarded.

It is not an error in python to discard a value.